# How to silently kill wiremock after Cypress test are executed?

Tags: npm, cypress, npm-scripts, wiremock, concurrently

I have an all-in-one npm script that:

- Starts a React application
- Starts Wiremock server in playback mode
- Executes Cypress tests silently

For that I'm using `concurrently`:

```
    "cypress:runner:one-shot": "concurrently npm:wiremock:playback npm:start:mock npm:cypress:execution:recorded",
```

After tests are executed I have to shut down the application and WireMock server.

For that, I added the following parameters to `concurrently` command:

```
--kill-others --success !command-0,!command-1
```

I need the all-in-one command to finish with an exit code **0**.
For some reason is still finishing with a **1** (given that WireMock server is killed)

**Is there any way to ignore the exit codes of any of those commands**?

Just in case:

`wiremock:playback` is something like

```
    "wiremock:playback": "npx  wiremock --proxy-all '...' --verbose --port 3001 --enable-stub-cors --root-dir wiremock",
```

Answer (score 1):

You can shut down WireMock by making a `POST` request to `/__admin/shutdown` (on the main host/port you configured WireMock to run on).